# How to get a reference to an object in a NavigationView Header

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my activity, I am inflating the layout via data binding. The binding itself works correctly, and I am able to get references to objects in the layout file easily.

One of those objects is a `NavigationView`. It has a `headerLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_view_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_view_color"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header" />
```

The header layout looks like this (extra objects removed for simplicity):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/menu_blue"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navViewLogOutButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logout"
        app:tint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sz.proApp.support.logOut" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need to set a click listener on this image view, but I can't get a reference to it. This is what I am using:

```
binding.navView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.navViewLogOutButton)?.setOnClickListener{
    doSomething()
}
```

I've verified that `binding.navView` is not `null`. Also, by setting a break point there, I can see what the memory address for this `ImageView` is. When I change that line to this:

```
binding.navView.findViewById<ImageView>(213123403)
```

I get the reference that I want. But obviously, I can't just use the integer since that is dynamic. The code compiles and the app launches. But when it hits that line, `findViewById` returns null every time.

I read that `findViewById` may not work with data binding in a activity, but if that is true, then how can I get this reference so that I can set the listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header"
> ```

So, the generated binding class should be`NavViewHeaderBinding`, you can get the binding with:

```
val headerBinding = NavViewHeaderBinding.bind(binding.navView.getHeaderView(0))
```

And access the header views through `headerBinding`:

```
headerBinding.navViewLogOutButton
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. I would not have realized that. One thing for anyone who stumbles on this post, which is kind of obvious, but bears mentioning: The constraintLayout in `nav_view_header.xml` needs to be wrapped in a `<layout>` tag to generate the binding file that you mentioned.